# How often do you have to log in to be an "active" user?

Tags: discussion, badges

In the summer, there will be a time (at least three months, eight max) where I will be 1000% unable to log in to this site (or use WiFi at all). So, I was just wondering if it will take me two years to get the active user badge?

Comment: Are you talking about [Enthusiast](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast) & [Fanatic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic), or about [Yearling](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling)?

Comment: @yannis Yearling. It says I have to be an active user for a year to earn the badge. I was just wondering what it means by "active." Once a month, once a week...

Comment: "Active member" for the purposes of the Yearling badge means "earning at least 200 reputation". You have already qualified, don't worry about those summer months. You will be awarded the badge once you have been a member for a year.